# Activating Bootstrap 4 drop-down menu elsewhere on page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap drop-down nav-bar at the top of my site.

I'm trying to show the 'helpDropDownMenuLink' drop-down when I click on a link elsewhere on the page.

Please could someone help me? I have read about $().dropdown('toggle') in the Bootstrap docs but have been unable to get it to work..!

Many thanks

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a id="helpDropdownMenuLink" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link">Help<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <div aria-labelledby="helpDropdownMenuLink" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="/link1" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="/link2" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is "elsewhere on page"? Do you mean a specific element or anywhere on the page? Please post complete example that demostrates the issue.

Comment: I meant in an <a> tag - Landa's solution worked for me, I just had to make sure that the JS code was added to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i imagine this is sort of what you need: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsj5o3j6/4/)

html

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary trigger_button">Trigger dropdown</button><br><br>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    Stuff...
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.trigger_button').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was actually having issues as I tried adding similar js code to the top of the page. Needed to move the code to the bottom for it to work.